# Image Stitching loop closure

Tags: c++, image-processing, boost, opencv, image-stitching

I have written an OpenCV program for stitching aerial images in c++, 
this is done by calculation the Homography of these images, and warping the 'tobe' stitched image to the original image.

> This stitching process is done by calculating the feature points in these images using SIFT or SURF feature detector, extractors.
>
> The process of how I stitch multiple images are accomplished by finding feature points iteratively, 
>   image1(scaled to the warp of image2) + image 2(warped) = imageStitch(combined/stitched);
>   (result from above)ImageStitch + image3 = imageStitch and so on !

I want to know the ways or methods to detect "LOOP CLOSURE" by knowing image feature points.

I hope this is clear
Thanks you for your reply

Comment: Please provide a better explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the homography between the images to close a loop since the homography warps the image to a single plane.
You should use only the 2D rotation and 2D translation which would be equivalent to warping to the surface of a cylinder or sphere.

Comment: could you explain me more please, do u know a paper or step by step method ? you are quite vague